# Routing path in Rails 3.1

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am getting the following error in Rails 3.1:

undefined local variable or method `sitemap_home_path' for #<#:0x71152b0>

The error comes from the line:

It looks like I defined my route incorrectly. I routes.rb this route is defined as following:

```
root :to => 'home#index'

resources :home do
  collection do
    .....
    get :sitemap
    .....
  end
end
```

So, I am expecting my url to be http://localhost:3000/home/sitemap where sitemap is sitemap.html.erb file under views/home. Could someone explain to me why in this case sitemap_home_path does not get created?

It was working fine with the following Rails 2.1 declaration:

```
 resources :home, :collection => {...., :sitemap => :get }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the desired url_path i.e. sitemap_home_path your routes.rb should be like this:

```
resource :home
  collection do
    get :sitemap
  end
end
```

The reason for this is that home is a resource that is always looked up without an ID. Therefore in this case you should use a singular resource. Please refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources and the rails guides in general as the article on routing is quite comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shirjeel! That was exactly what I was looking  for. I have read that doc, but I did not realize that besides "resources" there is a "resource" key word.

Answer (score 0):

Running `rake routes` is a great way to see what Rails is naming your routes. With your code, you'll probably see something similar to this:

```
sitemap_home_index GET    /home/sitemap(.:format)  {:action=>"sitemap", :controller=>"home"}
        home_index GET    /home(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"home"}
                   POST   /home(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"home"}
          new_home GET    /home/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"home"}
         edit_home GET    /home/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"home"}
              home GET    /home/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"home"}
                   PUT    /home/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"home"}
                   DELETE /home/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"home"}
```

So, you want to use `<%= link_to 'Sitemap', sitemap_home_index_path %>`.

Comment: Hi Dylan! Thanks a lot for the advice. I completely forgot about that command. Now it is clear. But I still can't bring the path to the right format. Could you please tell me how can I get rid of the _index part of sitemap_home_index_path?